# How to pass input to query rule defining a set document

Tags: open-policy-agent

In the documentation of OPA there are a lot of examples for generating sets/arrays/objects for querying, e.g.:

```
app_to_hostnames[app_name] = hostnames {
    app := apps[_]
    app_name := app.name
    hostnames := [hostname | name := app.servers[_]
                            s := sites[_].servers[_]
                            s.name == name
                            hostname := s.hostname]
}
```

However, in the documentation, all data is statically defined: in the example the variables `apps` already exists and is defined as some json object.

For reusability I would like to define a function that returns a set/array/object but allows for the input to be passed dynamically. In essence what I want to try to do is the following:

```
app_to_hostnames[app_name](apps) = hostnames {
    app := apps[_]
    app_name := app.name
    hostnames := [hostname | name := app.servers[_]
                            s := sites[_].servers[_]
                            s.name == name
                            hostname := s.hostname]
}
```

Where in this case apps is passed as a function input. Is there a way to achieve this in Rego policies? Or should I approach the problem in a different way? Or is there a way to pass different inputs to different policies?

I know you could send the input via the REST API to a specific policy and control it that way, but in this case I am using [conftest](https://github.com/instrumenta/conftest) which passes the input document (for example a json file) to a compiled set of rego policies) via the terminal so using the REST API won't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` and `data` documents are global. You can always replace their values on a given expression using the `with` keyword but sometimes it's more natural to wrap the logic in a function.

That specific example can be rewritten using a comprehension:

```
app_to_hostnames(apps, sites) = {app_name: hostnames |
    app := apps[_]
    app_name := app.name
    hostnames := [hostname | name := app.servers[_]
                            s := sites[_].servers[_]
                            s.name == name
                            hostname := s.hostname]
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `with` keyword to temporarily replace portions of the `data` or `input` documents. For example, if `apps`, `sites` were imported from under data in the file containing `app_to_hostnames` you could query `app_to_hostnames` as follows:

```
mock_apps := [
  {"name": "foo", "servers": ["s1"]},
  {"name": "bar", "servers": ["s2", "s3"]},
]

mock_sites := [
  {"servers": [{"name": "s1", "hostname": "x.com"}]},
  {"servers": [{"name": "s2", "hostname": "y.com"}, {"name": "s3", "hostname": "z.com"}]},
]

app_to_hostnames == {"foo": ["x.com"], "bar": ["y.com", "z.com"]} with data.apps as mock_apps with data.sites as mock_sites
```

Here's a link to the policy inside the playground: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/pEp6BLCtgn